# GUI wont show labels and text fields when Spring layout is added

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager, border-layout

I used Grid layout first, Then i realized i wanted to use spring layout instead. When i add Spring layout Panel nothing wants to show

```
public class ComplexWindow extends JFrame {

    public ComplexWindow() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(10, 10, 300, 420);
        JPanel mainPanel = (JPanel) getContentPane();
        mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
        JPanel textPanel = new JPanel(layout);
        JLabel lblName = new JLabel("Ime:");
        textPanel.add(lblName);
        JTextField txtName = new JTextField();
        txtName.setColumns(10);
        textPanel.add(txtName);
        JLabel lblSurname = new JLabel("Prezime:");
        textPanel.add(lblSurname);
        JTextField txtSurname = new JTextField();
        txtSurname.setColumns(10);
        textPanel.add(txtSurname);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, lblName, 5, 
            SpringLayout.WEST, txtName);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, lblName, 5, 
            SpringLayout.NORTH, lblSurname);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, txtName, 5, 
            SpringLayout.NORTH, txtSurname);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, lblSurname, 5, 
            SpringLayout.WEST, txtSurname);
        mainPanel.add(textPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            ComplexWindow window = new ComplexWindow();
            window.pack();
            window.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `didn't write lines 33-36,` - we don't know what lines you are referring to. `When i add Spring layout Panel nothing wants to show` - then I would suggest you didn't add the constraints correctly. People generally don't use this layout because of its complexity. I suggest you start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Spring Layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html). Download the working example and customize it to do what you want. Add/remove one component at a time and then retest. If it stops working you not what you changed.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, i will go through it tomorrow

Comment: Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Answer (score 0):

As this documentation says, `SpringLayout` is not for manual laying out of components:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html

> SpringLayout is, however, very low-level and as such you really should
>   only use it with a GUI builder, rather than attempting to code a
>   spring layout manager by hand.

And also, a utility class used in above tutorial `layout.SpringUtilities` is not included in JDK.

So, I recommend you use `GridBagLayout` for this.